# Number of columns for mobile devices in grid systems

Tags: grids, mobile, bootstrap

Currently designing in Adobe XD me and my team were discussing about the perfect approach to grid systems. How in You opinion should we handle the number of columns for mobile devices?

**1. Go the standard way and get rid of some columns**:

```
desktop - 12 columns
tablets - 8 columns
phones - 4 columns
```

**2. Resize the columns width and gutter and stay 12 columns all devices?**

Comment: This depends fully on the context and content. Voting to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Going with option one is preferable. Resizing the columns down doesn't give you any advantage. If you think about an object spanning col 6-9 as opposed to 6-10 on that small phone screen, the visual difference will be quite small. Honestly, it may be perceived as an error not as your intention.